# Get some random element from an Array on Iteration

Tags: javascript

Ok this is my first time with asking for help in this community and I'll try to be as specific as I can. Here is what I want to achieve.
I want to give a list of 4 keys from the array which need to be unique obviously. I will put the below in a `for` loop but am i on the right track below

Given an array of elements in the array...

```
var keysRand = new Array("E","F","G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "F#", "G#", "A#", "D#", "C#")
```

I want to go through the array, pick a random key:

```
randno1 = keysRand[Math.floor( Math.random() * keysRand.length )];
```

Get the index of the Key I choose

```
var a = keysRand.indexOf(randno1)
```

Push it to top of list and get rid of it.

```
keysRand.push(keysRand.splice(a, 1)[0]);
keysRand1.pop();
```

This seems to work most of the time but im seeing undefined entries sometimes when doing `console.log()`.
Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that [`Array#splice` is destructive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): it returns a popped element and mutates the original array so it doesn't contain that element.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `keysRand.splice(a, 1)` actually removes the element by itself and there is no need to then move it and pop it.

### For Example:

What you have here:

```
keysRand.push(keysRand.splice(a, 1)[0]);
keysRand1.pop();
```

Should just be:

```
keysRand.splice(a, 1)
```

### Also

You already have the index with: `Math.floor( Math.random() * keysRand.length )`, so your whole code can be shortened to:

```
var keysRand = new Array("E","F","G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "F#", "G#", "A#", "D#", "C#");
var index = Math.floor( Math.random() * keysRand.length );
keysRand.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: How do i just remove the one i have chosen from the Array?

Comment: Note quite sure what you are saying, that's what `splice` does.

Comment: when running this a few times the console.log returns some undefined entries..
var keysRand1 = new Array("E","F","G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "F#", "G#", "A#", "D#", "C#")    
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  randno1 = keysRand1[Math.floor( Math.random() * keysRand.length )];
  var a = keysRand1.indexOf(randno1)
  console.log(randno1);
  keysRand1.splice(a, 1)
      
  }

Comment: What is `keysRand` in `keysRand.length`?

Comment: When outputting the length i get positive result 12,11,10,9 which is good. However when outputting the key it's showing me a duplicate key. perhaps this has something to do where the console.log() is located in the script